# Android Open Image in Toolbar like Whatsapp profile

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, toolbar, whatsapp

I have a toolbar with an ImageView, the toolbar allows scroll and slide.

I am looking for a way to create an interface like whatsapp's profile.

I need to have the possibility to click on the ImageView which is inside the toolbar and after pop-up another interface(or activity) which allow to save or zoom the image (like whatsapp's profile picture).

**Google provide ZoomView but it isn't enough, I don't need only to zoom the Image, maybe I need to create another Activity, I don't know where to start**

Example of what I get if I click an image:

[image]

Comment: I think you can use android support design library.. a useful tutorial:
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: @RezaBigdeli I don't think I need to create it on my own, I noticed that a lot of app have the same interface, maybe is something like a "gallery" in Android

Comment: check this http://valuestack.io/index.php/2016/10/14/whats-app-like-colour-changing-collapsing-tool-bar-using-palette/  for  whats app like collapsing tool bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:
https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

and this:
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Android Studio with Google Design library,
which supports - CoordinatorLayout, with Collapsing Tool Bar layout
like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="312dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDetailView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:title="Outlet Details"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="Outlet Details" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

And setup the toolbar with menu items in onCreatOptionsMenu method.

check for the click event for imageview and on click of image view 
change the content with another fragment that has same like above.

Comment: I know how to create toolbar, use material design. The question was about how to achive what I said. I need to create on my own the interface for the image or there are other ways? A lot of app have the same interface, I think they use a kind of default viewer